# Unable to query ports on windows network

Tags: networking, windows-8, tcpip, network-monitoring

I have 2 environments that need to speak with each other, 2 servers are sitting in our test environment and 1 is in our corp environment.

[image]

Client A was setup over a year ago and works as expected, I am unsure if there is a IPSec exception and I used to have a script that helped me figure that out.

Client B we are setting up now and although it is in the same address space as Client A, it is unable to query the ports on the SQLWorker.

I have setup Netmon traces on both ends and when I do a portquery with Client A, I see a full handshake but when I do it with B, I the following flag patter:
Syn
SynReTransmit
SynRetransmit

This is the cap from the end point (SQLWorker), the client side shows identical output. So it seems they are able to see each other but something is refusing the connection somewhere and I am unable to determine what the cause is. Any help is appreciated! Thank you

[image: Netmon Cap]

Comment: How is the translation from xx.x.132.x to x.x.164.x being done?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by translation but I am using Microsoft Portquery when querying these ports. I have also tried simply browsing to that server as well.

There is possibly a hardware firewall on the destination side but would that not block all traffic from even reaching the SQLWorker?

Comment: There is going to be routing and/or NAT'ing that joins the two different subnets. You have to figure out how that's setup as it may only be allowing certain IPs through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network devices where not at fault for this issue as the packet was able to reach the destination but not back. This was due to a special boundary exception that needed to be added to allow communication between 2 domains that have no trust.

Oh the cool things I learn as I go :)

Thank you all for your help!